# Missing bytes when calling HttpServletRequest.getInputSteam() method

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, dropwizard

I am creating Restful web service that accepts any file and saves it into filesystem. I am using Dropwizard to implement the service and Postman/RestClient to hit the request with data. I am not creating multipart (form-data) request.

Every thing is working fine except the file saved has first character missing. Here is my code for calling the service method and saving it into file system:

Input Request:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/request/Sample.txt
```

Sample.txt

```
Test Content
```

Rest Controller

```
@PUT
@Consumes(value = MediaType.WILDCARD)
@Path("/test/request/{fileName}")
public Response authenticateDevice(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

.......
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    writeFile(inputStream, fileName);
......
}
private void writeFile(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {

        File file = new File(this.directory);
        file.mkdirs();
        if (file.exists()) {
            os = new FileOutputStream(this.directory + fileName);
            logger.info("File Written Successfully.");
        } else {
            logger.info("Problem Creating directory. File can not be saved!");
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        int n;
        while ((n = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in writing to File::" + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            os.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error in closing input/output stream::" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

In output, file is saved but first character from the content is missing. 
Output:

Sample.txt:

```
   est Content
```

In above output file, character T is missing and this happens for all the file formats.

I don't know what point I am missing here.

Please help me out on this.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you verified the sending code? For example to use local proxy or any other way to get access to the contents of the sent request.

Comment: Try the same with uploading your file, but use curl instead. If it works, then your client is the problem. Example curl command: curl -i -F name=test -F filedata=@localfile.jpg http://example.org/upload

Comment: Just tested this, using curl and it uploaded the whole file
Used: 
glyn$ curl -i -X PUT --data-binary @test.txt localhost:8080/upload/wibble